# Vaadin Grid invoke inline edit

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my web application I'm using `Grid` component to render a table with some data. I'm using `grid.setEditorEnabled(true)` to enable inline editing on double click on the row. I also have an edit button from [GridUtil addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/gridutil), on which I'd like to enter inline edit mode on click. Is there a way how to invoke it?

I've tried to find something like selection or edit listener but with no success. Note that inline edit is a standard feature in `Grid`, not an addon.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this should be possible fairly easy. Supposing we're using a `BeanItemContainer`, it would be something along the lines of `grid.getColumn("id").setRenderer(new EditButtonValueRenderer(event -> grid.editItem(event.getItemId())));`. It may still require some tweaking to handle clicks while the editor is already visible, but seemd doable...